# vue create my-app doesn't find package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3

Hellon trying to create a new Vue3 app, but get an error message begining with packake.json not found.

Clean (think so...) installation done for node + npm + vue on mac :

- deleted all node in usr/local/lib/node_modules, brew uninstall node / install node.
  Versions : node 17.4.0 + npm 8.3.2
- npm install -g @vue/cli
  Version @vue/cli 4.5.5
- try a new vue3 project : vue create my-app

Done these actions several times in the past. But get a very long message of errors, beginning with a "module not found" :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:347
        throw err;
        ^
```

Error: Command failed: npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:

- /Users/thierry/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /Users/thierry/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /Users/thierry/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  ...

...
at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at Function.module.exports.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
at new PackageManager (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/ProjectPackageManager.js:126:42)
...

Found several package.json in usr/local/lib/node_modules :

- npm/package.json
- @vue/cli/package.json
- the last seems to be the one pointed from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js

Tried similar questions here and there, but can't find an answer. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

solved question, i must have sent a local command for command instead o f using -g option. Confusion the local and global installations after that.